# Book Recommendation for Analyzing Experimental Results

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation, data-analysis

I am starting an internship in a few weeks in a research lab. In preparation, I have read a bunch of books and articles on the subject that will be explored. However I feel myself lacking in one major aspect of the whole research process, namely statistical analysis. I would like to find a book that deals with analyzing experimental results and quantitatively comparing them with theoretical models and simulation results. I am not talking about an introduction to statistics or probability. I am looking for more advanced tools of study.

Any helpful recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: This is a cross post from Stats SE - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325163/book-recommendation-for-analyzing-experimental-results

Comment: @GaurangTandon I deleted it there, thought maybe it was better asked here.

Comment: If you're looking for classical analytic methods, one of the standard texts is the one by Snececor and Cochran. The book is mathematically correct but oriented toward applications. (Iowa State U has a lot of agricultural experimentation going on.) However, you won't find such computationally intensive methods as simulated permutation tests and bootstrap confidence intervals there. Nor will you find anything about Bayesian statistical analysis. And nothing about simulation. // Of course, there are many other good choices, and which one you pick should be a matter of personal preferance.